# Разные package id системного приложения на разных устройствах

Tags: java, android, activity

Нужно открыть активити контактов через приложение, делаю это так:

```
public void openContactList(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Дело в том, что на андроид `4.4.2` всё работает, но на `4.2.2` программа вылетает. Думаю что проблема, в разных названиях пакетов где находятся контакты.

**Вопрос в следующем:**

как можно и где посмотреть эту часть  (`com.android.contacts` и  `com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity`) для другой версии андроид (ну если это для всех версий одинаково где можно это найти)?

Comment: попробуйте на grepcode.com посмотреть http://grepcode.com/search?query=com.android.contacts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!! 
Чтоб вы посоветовали прочитать  по этой теме???

Comment: @Vitaliy, я бы посоветовал почитать гугл. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20select%20contact%20from%20phonebook&es_th=1